# How to return Meteor Blaze content for specific location through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: meteor-blaze, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to send a request via reverse proxy, perform the rendering on the upstream server with locally-available data, and return fully-rendered HTML in the response to be served to the client.  Although the rendering seems to work fine for the root location, I am having issues getting the correctly-rendered content when routing to a secondary upstream server for a specific location.

We want to run separate Meteor applications that communicate with each other: one will be the main portal where users log in, and the rest will be different game servers that each host their own game sessions and perform calculations on their local data.  The portal should route to the correct game server, and the individual game server should return the rendered content.

Based on what I've read, I suspect that Blaze and IronRouter on the upstream server may be an issue for this setup. I'm posting for either confirmation that I need to get rid of Blaze and IronRouter, or in case someone knows of a potential solution that allows me to return content rendered by Blaze through the reverse proxy.

This is the desired setup:

- Clients access the public nameserver at https://games.example.com.
- The authentication app controls user login and holds references to the user's game sessions.
- When a user attempts to access a game session from the authentication app, the route sends a request to nginx with the appropriate http headers specifying the session id and an identifying key for the correct upstream server.
- The upstream server runs all the game logic and houses game session data locally.  When it receives the request, it builds the appropriate content with the correct reactive data and returns the response, which should be rendered to the user's browser.

We are willing to explore alternate solutions such as converting to React and server-side rendering, but I want to make sure that I'm not missing any workable functionality with Blaze.

Note: We absolutely want a reverse proxy solution so that users never see a different public domain.  We don't want to redirect to different visible subdomains.

I've tried a few things.

1) Without changing the Blaze/IronRouter setup, I tried to used nginx proxy pass to forward the request to the upstream game server when a certain non-root location was visited on the default server.  In the server block, I attempted to point to the upstream server at a specific route for the game session.  This led to an infinite loop because nginx was unable to find the content files.  I haven't the slightest clue what root folder to tell nginx to check for existing content files, because I don't think Blaze generates any?  This led me to attempt to return rendered content in different ways in 2) and 3).

2) I tried using IronRouter's Restful routes to capture requests server side and return some response, but somehow I could not get the route handlers to be invoked.  I got the feeling that the requests weren't recognized as get / post.  I would send a get / post request from the portal application, but the routes defined in the game server application didn't seem to catch the requests, and therefore I was unable to properly return a response.  I was hoping that IronRouter could've returned the rendered content that was linked to the Blaze template, but I don't think I used it correctly.

3) I tried the built-in Meteor webapp connect handler, and this was able to detect the requests (and confirm the correct request headers) as well as return a test response with hardcoded content.  However, the request would be singular; if I'm not mistaken, I'd need some sort of long polling solution to update the data.  With our game server app, data updates very frequently and we need that to show almost in real time.  I'm hoping that there's a way to get the correct content from Blaze and send it in the response, since Blaze plays nicely with the reactivity on the game server, but if this is impossible, we can explore other options.

Here's my example nginx setup that I've been testing locally.  I fire up two Meteor apps locally to test.  In a production environment, the apps would be on completely different servers.  They would not be at different ports on the same server.

Note: The company cannot afford nginx plus, so we are using the tengine fork.

Portal app:

```
meteor run --port=3000
```

Game server app (sharing portal app's user db):

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor; meteor run --port=5000
```

- Default server is localhost:80 and I type that url into the browser.
- The portal Meteor application is at localhost:3000. Default server reverse proxies here from root location.
- A separate game server application is at localhost:5000.  I want the reverse proxy to grab content responses from there upon visiting a defined location.

From the portal app at port 3000, I send a request to /revprox/instsession/.  The request headers contain the session id (X-Session-Id) and upstream game server key (X-Game-Server).

```
events {}

http {
  upstream meteor {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=2s;
    check interval=1000 rise=2 fall=2 timeout=1000 type=http;
  }

  upstream game1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=2s;
    check interval=1000 rise=2 fall=2 timeout=1000 type=http;
  }

  upstream game2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:6000 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=2s;
    check interval=1000 rise=2 fall=2 timeout=1000 type=http;
  }

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
  }

  # Map to different upstream backends based on header
  # Format is header_value "upstream_server_name"
  map $http_x_game_server $game_server {
    default "meteor";
    game1 "game1";
    game2 "game2";
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost:3000;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri 404;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://meteor;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    }

    location /revprox/instsession/ {

      proxy_pass $scheme://$game_server/instInstructor/$http_x_session_id;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header Proxy '';
      proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Original-Request $request_uri;
      proxy_set_header X-Game-Server $game_server;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to get any rendered response from the upstream game server by defining a route in IronRouter.  (When trying to use IronRouter, I comment out any connect handler code so that it doesn't interfere.) I've tried many incarnations of it, tried server side or client side, with or without Restful routes, etc. all to no avail.  Here's an example route definition:

```
Router.route('instInstructor', { path: '/instInstructor/:_id', onBeforeAction: 'instInstructorInit', where: 'server' })
```

Alternatively, if I define a connectHandler on server startup, it returns the expected content, which then shows up in my browser.  The request headers are also as expected (see below).

```
Meteor.startup ->
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/instInstructor', (req, res, next) ->
    res.writeHead 200
    console.log req.headers
    res.end "hi did you reach me"
  );

Headers:
{ 'x-forwarded-host': 'localhost',
 'x-forwarded-port': '80',
'x-session-id': 'bJqTeSG4j5C8qTCvi',
connection: 'close',
'x-game-server': 'game1',
'x-original-request': '/revprox/instsession/',
'x-forwarded-proto': 'http,http',
'x-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1',
referer: 'http://localhost:80/revprox/instsession',
host: 'localhost' }
```

Regardless of how it is set up, I need the game server to render the content and return it in the response to the forwarded reverse proxy request.  I want to serve that rendered content on the public-facing site.

Do we need to get rid of Blaze and IronRouter in favor of a different solution?  Have I overlooked some Blaze features that would give me what I need without having to switch away from Blaze?  Is my nginx configuration just completely wrong?

Any help or suggestions would be fantastic.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you simplify this question to its core problem? It is hard to fiddle out the main problem. Is you problem routing, rendering or sending data?

Comment: Hi Jankapunkt, so sorry about the lack of clarity.  I edited my post a bit; could you let me know if it's still unclear?  I believe my main problem is rendering.  However, it's possible because I am new to nginx that I have a routing problem that I'm not aware of.  I'm not sure if there's a configuration that I'm missing that could get me the correct content from Blaze without having to take additional steps to generate content via SSR and update data via long polling.

Comment: If you define a connect handler you need to manually invoke Blaze to directly render into the response which is difficult and hacky. An easier option would be to render your pages by Blaze (using the router only to navigate between blaze templates) und define your api using different (!) routes to send / receive data via HTTPS. Does that bring you further?

Comment: That makes sense, I'd love to get it working that way.  I don't like the connect handler because a single request wouldn't respond to reactive data changes, there would need to be constant requests.  [EDIT]: Sorry, posted too early. I'm having issues making the router work.  For some reason, when I forward the request via reverse proxy to the upstream game server that's supposed to render, it seems that IronRouter never gets reached and I don't get any Blaze rendering.  Instead, nginx grabs the html at the root location and sends it back.  Is this an nginx config issue or my router setup?